# Redis sorted set , fetching all member having score less than x

Tags: redis

In Redis,How to fetch all member having score less than x ?
And what will be time complexity of doing that task?

Comment: Might I suggest you take a look at the wonderful redis documentation? It has explanations, time complexity and use-cases for all commands. See [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands/#sorted_set).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) redis command.

e.g. the members with score less than 4

```
zadd myset 1 "one"
zadd myset 2 "two"
zadd myset 3 "three"
zadd myset 5 "five"
zadd myset 6 "six"

ZRANGEBYSCORE myset -inf 4
```

result:

```
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
```

also for score greater than 4

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myset 4 +inf
```

result:

```
1) "five"
2) "six"
```

About the complexity, due to the redis documentation it is O(log(N)+M)

EDIT:
2nd example

Let's say that we have a scoreboard of an online game, which we store in a sorted set in redis.
The following command creates this test

```
zadd scoreboard 101 "John" 333 "Mary" 323 "Nick" 900 "Steve" 901 "Sam" 333 "Mike"
```

The players that qualify to the next round are the ones with the score less than 330. To find these players we run the following command.

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE scoreboard -inf 330
```

which will result to 2 players (John and Nick)

```
1) "John"
2) "Nick"
```

To explain a bit further this command:
ZRANGEBYSCORE: the redis command, check the documentation
scoreboard: the sorted-set that I created
-inf: is the minimum price of my command
330: the maximum price of my command

What it does is to find all members in this range from -infinite to 330, which I understand as all the members from 330 and below.

I hope that I helped :)

Comment: This command will help only if I know the range. But in this case I don't know the range stored in set.

Comment: In my example x = 4, it returns all the members with score 4 and smaller for an infinite range (-inf).

Comment: Can you please give example of minimum value?

Comment: I edited my answer with a second example. Try the 2 commands with the redis-cli (first to create the sorted-set and then to find the minimum).

Comment: @VivekGoel: It's perfectly clear. Your question, *How to fetch all member having score less than x ?*. The answer is `ZRANGEBYSCORE -inf x`, where `x` is a score you supply.

Comment: @LinusGThiel sorry I think I mixed two question :(.

Comment: "ZRANGEBYSCORE -inf x, where x is a score you supply" returns everything with a score of x-or-less, including x, so it's not the answer to "how to fetch numbers having scores less than x", but to "less than or equal to x"...